# Why Cython extensions on Windows depend on pythonXX.dll but not on MacOSX?

Tags: python, windows, macos, dll, cython

I built the same libraries ( example below is from rfoo ) on windows and mac, and the mac version only has system dependencies

```
$ otool -L marsh.so 
marsh.so:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

while on windows it depends on python's dll

```
>dumpbin /dependents marsh.pyd
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 12.00.31101.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file marsh.pyd

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    python25.dll
    MSVCR120.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
```

I wonder if it's an implementation choice that is not really due to windows, or if there is something specific to windows that requires this.

Context: I use this to load python extensions from within an embed interpreter inside Ableton Live, which uses an old python version ; but the worst is that python is not loaded as a library, it's statically linked inside the software. On mac, it's not a problem, I can still load the extension. On windows, I can't, because I have to link to python25.dll, but then at load it tries to initialize again the interpreter, which gives an error, since the dll is not used by Ableton Live. I wonder if there is some hope to have it work on windows.

Comment: Windows doesn't pool global symbols into a common namespace. Modules (DLLs) have to explicitly export and import symbols. Does the embedded Python include the `_ctypes` extension module? Otherwise maybe you could do something with an RPC to another process.

Comment: Thanks, so that's why. I thought about ctypes but it comes with a dll ( more exactly a pyd ) as well, and it has been stripped. So long story short, my most critical feature relies on zeromq and as it seems it's no more an option if I want portability ( there is a "pure python" alternative but it ends up relying on pywin32 which as binaries ). I opened a question in their beta site but I don't have much hope. I'm currently reimplementing the network part using asyncore, not as nice but available and viable.

Answer (score -1):

There are DLL on OS X and as opposed to Windows, most OS X applications are statically linked, bigger but with less external dependencies.

Comment: Actually the first comment is the right answer. Won't judge if the statement is true or false, it's just unrelated.